# Looking for construct simto VB's WITH statement

Tags: fortran

Updating some archaic F77 that no longer fully supported our needs. I am looking for the functional equivalent of VB's "WITH" statement to support the conversion from a mass of F77 disconnected, individual variables to hierarchical derived Types. While the code is much easier to read and understand the downside is that the code becomes very cumbersome and prone to typos. So, the use of WITH would greatly ease the conversion burden.

VB's "WITH" statement executes a series of statements on a single object or a user-defined type.
Example:
if I want to reference elements my derived Type named Loads I would write code with Loads% prefixing each element and that is cumbersome. The WITH statement allows one to re-write the block with an assumed reference to Loads%.

```
WITH Loads%
   ID = blah
   Description = blahblah
   Duty(I) = 2
End WITH
```

Suggestions...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no Fortran construct which provides a precise analog to what you describe as VB's `with` statement.  For your particular example, you could write something along the lines of ...

Given a derived type definition such as

```
type :: load
    character(4) :: id
    character(32) :: description
    integer, dimension(4) :: duties
end type load
```

and a variable of that type

```
type(load) :: loads
```

you can use a default constructor to set the values of the members of `loads`, like this:

```
loads = load('myid', 'my description', [1,2,3,4])
```

or even like this:

```
loads = load(duties=[3,4,5,6], id = 'id2', description='description')
```

If you look around on SO for Qs and As on the subject of *Fortran derived type constructor* you'll find out how to build more complicated constructors which don't need all the members to be given values when they are called.  There are some useful resources elsewhere on the internet too.

If one of your concerns is to avoid typing long, and possibly multipart, entity names then the `associate` construct might help.  For example, if, rather than `loads` the name of the variable you wanted to avoid typing was something like `long%structured%entity` you might write

```
associate (shnm => long%structured%entity`)
    shnm%id = 'idxx'
    *etc*
end associate
```

I'm sure you could easily come up with more extensive examples of the use of `with` which would not be easy to translate to Fortran without repeated writing of `loads%`.

Comment: Thx @HighPerformanceMark, 'Associate' is a reasonable analog to address the goal of my question. Much obliged.